# SASS media queries best practise?

Tags: css, sass

Is it ok to nest media queries inside an element? If I want to use `min-width: 480px` in another places there will be huge repetition. Please look at my code example. Or just use the old way? Any idea?

**SASS**

```
.navbar {
     height: 500px;
     width: 500px;

     @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
         background-color: lightgreen;
     }
}

.items {
    padding: 15px;
    color: red;

    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   .navbar {
       background-color: lightgreen;
   }

   .items {
       border: 1px solid black;
   }
}
```

Comment: Really depends on the project imo. For smaller projects, I believe the initial one is okay as long as it is readable. But for best practice I would use the "old" way of defining your media queries. You might want to look into ITCSS

Comment: Imo this is absolutely the best way to do it. To avoid "huge repetition" why not just store `min-width: 480px` as a variable? `@media screen and ($resolution--small) { ... }` or something...

Comment: @EdmundReed: But It's also repeating the media query statement.

Comment: sure, in that case you could create a custom mixin and just do @include resolution--small {...} or something, but that's sort of beyond the scope of the question. Besides, the alternative is to repeat the class name/selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$pc: 1024px;    // PC screen size.
$tablet: 720px; // Tablet screen size.
$phone: 320px;  // Phone screen size.

@mixin responsive($media) {
  @if $media= phone {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $tablet - 1) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $media= tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $tablet - 1) and (max-width: $pc) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $media= pc {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $pc + 1) and (min-width: $pc) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $media= pc_tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $tablet - 1) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

Examples

```
body {
  @include responsive(pc) {
    background: red;
  }
  @include responsive(tablet) {
    background: yellow;
  }
  @include responsive(phone) {
    background: green;
  }
}
```